# Scala, SBT and IntelliJ modules

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, module, sbt

I am curious about a way to have different projects sharing code without resorting to a common library. I am looking at IntelliJ modules.

Is it possible to have a single IntelliJ project consisting of independent modules, each one with its own SBT file and plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in IntelliJ, click "file -> new -> module from existing sources" to import an SBT project as a module.